# Applying the Green´s second identity in the unit disk

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Maybe this is trivial. Let assume that U and W are polynomials (in the reals with real coeffs) defined in the unit disk, can we apply the Green´s second identity on the unit disk?, are not U and W non differentiable at the boundary?

Let say, W is one of the Zernike polynomials, i.e., orthonormal polynomials defined in the unit disk ($\rho\leq 1$), and are not defined for $\rho>1$. So has W a discontinuity at the boundary and wouldn't it be non differentiable?

U can be another one from a set of polynomials also defined in the unit disk, and zero beyond it. Wouldn't it be also non differentiable at the disk boundary?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Aren't polynomials defined and smooth on all the plane?

Comment: U and W are defined on the unit disk, not in all the plane. That is why my concern, beyond the boundary U and W are not defined (are zero).

Comment: You need to put more details in your questions! Polynomials are polynomials.

Comment: Sorry I am not a mathematician. Some edit adding more details.